# jQuery - Library use in id selector in generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery

In standard generated content, we use function like this:

```
$(document).on('click', "date_picker", function(){
  alert("hello");
});
```

But how do we use in a function in generated content, for example the datepicker library from jQuery UI?

Example of what i am trying to say

```
$(document).on('click', 'date_picker').datepicker();
```

Comment: Normally you'd just select the element and call the plugin straight on that. ie. `$("input.class_on_date_fields").datepicker();` the plugin should then attach all the necessary events itself.

Comment: After the "generated content" (usually the callback of an ajax request) is attached to the web page (new DOM nodes are created and then attached to the DOM tree) you can call again the plugin method.

Answer (score 0):

Once your dynamic content has been loaded, call the plugin like you normally would, ex:

```
$("#myDiv").load(somePath, function(data) {
    $("#myLoadedContentID").datepicker();
});
```